# Restore of .bak file fails for SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

When I try to restore a `.bak` file in SQL Server 2008, then its original file name remains `testDB`.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore failed for Server 'T-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: what are those two media's...

Comment: `The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided`

Answer (score 1):

The backup was split across 2 files/devices, you need to provide all of the files to be able to restore it.